# subprocess Popen not able to execute shell script

Tags: python, cgi

I have the following python code below which works if I execute it in REPL. However when I run the script it doesn't even open script1.sh shell script.

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen

p = subprocess.Popen(["./script1.sh","-a",param1],stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate()
print("Output: ", out)
print("Error: ", err)
```

It doesn't have any syntax errors but I found the following differences in output.

Output when running python script

```
('Output: ', 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;\nExpires: 0;\nLast-Modified: Mon Apr 16 09:11:01 GST 2018\nCache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate;\n\n')
('Error: ', '')
```

Output when running python code from REPL

```
('Output: ', 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8;\nExpires: 0;\nLast-Modified: Mon Apr 16 05:07:08 GMT 2018\nCache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate;\n\n**File\x02/path_to_file/generate_file.txt**\n')
('Error: ', '')
```

As shown the output when executing python script from REPL generates the file but not for normal python script execution. Any idea why this is the case?

Comment: You can try providing absolute path for the shell script , script1.sh

Comment: For those of us not in the know... what is REPL?

Comment: @AkshayValsa Are you suggesting that the script can't be found? Then it most certainly not be giving output like Content-Type etc.... I don't see how an absolute path there makes a difference.

Comment: The acronym stands for read evaluate print loop. but basically its when you type python from command line and you are able to type in your code line by line and directly processes it ... that's how i understood it ...

Comment: @AkshayValsa I agree with tdelaney it didn't make any difference... but when tried it with absolute path on python script it didn't work. But it works if i try it on python command line

Comment: @dimas, ok, how do you run it from the command line ?

Comment: Oh, okay, so that's just running in the python shell with the ">>> " prompt. It works when you do `python3` and then just type it in, but fails when you run `python3 nameofmyscript.py`.   Did I get that right?!

Comment: ...and you are in the same directory in each case and `param1` is the same both times?

Comment: @tdelaney yes to both questions... not really sure why there is a difference in behaviour

Comment: @dimas, may be the program picking up different bash, try using shell=True in Popen command, or specify the respective shell in the command itself like, /bin/sh ./script1.sh

Comment: @Akshay tried different variations including your suggestion... but still didn't work... also tried Call and it only works when its called in python shell.